# Intellij insists on compiling with javac 11.0.3 instead of Java 7

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a project with many modules, all of which need to be compiled using Java 7. I have made sure every setting that I know of to point to that version of Java, yet somehow, every time I rebuild the project I get:

```
Information:javac 11.0.3 was used to compile java sources
```

followed by a list of errors:

```
Warning:(86, 25) java: as of release 9, '_' is a keyword, and may not be used as an identifier

Error:(86, 25) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class _
  location: class com.(...)`
```

Following other questions like:

[Can't resolve -source errors on IntelliJ with regards to Project Language Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198264/cant-resolve-source-errors-on-intellij-with-regards-to-project-language-level?newreg=5bb8e7355c8342798dd1f335e9f3bf4e)

[IntelliJ IDEA tells me "Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error idea"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966889/intellij-idea-tells-me-errorjava-compilation-failed-internal-java-compiler-e)

I have tried these settings:

- Under Project Structure -> Project -> Project SDK: 1.7
- Project Structure -> Project language level -> 7 - Diamonds, ARM, multi-catch etc.
- Under Project Structure -> Modules checked every module, and that was not fun, because there are about 50. Sources tab -> Language level: Project detaulf (7 - Diamonds, ARM, multi-catch etc.)
- Project Structure -> Modules, each Dependencies tab -> Module SDK: Project SDK (1.7)
- Project Structure -> SDKs: it listed IDEA's built in Java 11, so I removed it, leaving only: 1.7
- Settings -> Java Compiler -> Use compiler: Javac
- Settings -> Java Compiler -> Use compiler from module target JDK when possible: unticked
- Settings -> Java Compiler -> Per-module bytecode version: all modules set to 1.7

I am running the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-192.5728.98, built on July 23, 2019
```

Is this a bug with IDEA?

Comment: Wait, you have a class named `_`?

Comment: @Thomas looking at it, it points to a line `@Getter(onMethod = @__(@JSONProperty(ignoreIfNull = true)))` it's the `_` after the @
disclaimer: I did not write this code, I don't know what that line does :)

Comment: Have you tried to `Switch the boot JDK` ?

Comment: @ArnaudClaudel could you provide a bit more background? I'm not sure what that means

Comment: It changes the runtime of IntelliJ, maybe it used by default for compilation. [Source](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html)

Comment: Are you using a build system such as Gradle or Maven? Is that configured for jdk1.7 too? What happens if you just type `gradle build` on the command line?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException we have maven, I think the equivalent would be using `mvn compile`, and that finishes with a BUILD SUCCESS. Not sure where you specify JDK in pom though, but running the script through IDE logged out that it executed with the correct default JDK

Answer (score 3):

Here is the reason Intellij is choosing java 11: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-build-jdk.html

> IntelliJ IDEA checks all JDKs that are used in the project: the JDKs
>   that are defined on both the project and module levels.
>
> IntelliJ IDEA calculates the latest of these JDKs. This is necessary
>   to make sure that all modules can be compiled.
>
> **If the version of the latest JDK configured is lower than 1.6,
>   IntelliJ IDEA will pick the JDK version that is used for running the
>   IDE.** This limitation is related to the fact that the compiler API used
>   by IntelliJ IDEA for building projects is supported starting from JDK
>   1.6.

And that is why [switching the boot JDK to JDK8](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) re-enables the compilation of older java classes.

Comment: Ok, but the project's version that I mention in my question relies on JDK 1.7, so it shouldn't do that according to this

Comment: You are right, I had a similar problem but with a module still using JDK 1.4.

In your case it should work since no JDK lower than 1.6 is configured. So maybe this is a bug in Intellij-IDEA?

Comment: This bug might be related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209978

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @Arnaud Claudel, I have tried switching the boot JDK of IDEA (described here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html) which helped. Incidentally, the lowest JDK version that IDEA will accept is 8.

I am not sure it is actual solution though and not just a workaround, because why would the IDE use JDK 11 in the first place, ignoring all the project's settings.
So I am leaving this question open for anyone to post a better solution.

Comment: I think this can be an actual solution because support matrix for IntelliJ is determined by Jet Brains. Minimum JDK accepted for that version could be 8. I assure you, there is almost no chance of coming up with a better solution.

Comment: Are you suggesting Jet Brains is dropping support for JDK7 projects within IntelliJ? Because I don't think that's what's happening.

Comment: Actually Java 7 itself has reached end of public update and support from Oracle. Oracle suggested existing Java 7 customers to migrate to later versions as early as April 2015. https://java.com/en/download/faq/java_7.xml

Comment: In such a scenario, you cannot expect IDEs to support all versions although the language supports backward compatibility